# VS2015 Nuget zombie cache

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I am having a strange problem where VS2015 is caching a stale copy of a (private) nuget package that had a dependency problem, but that package has since been rebuilt with the same version number minus the dependency problems.  No matter what I do, VS2015 seems to be conjuring this old broken package out of the aether somewhere.  I have cleared appdata\local\Nuget\cache (both v2 and v3 caches).  I have deleted the packages folder.  I have used the package manager to reinstall the package.  Nothing seems to work.  I know this is a VS2015 issue because when I run VS2012 and install the package from that environment, the correct package is installed without dependency issues.

Does anyone know where VS2015 is getting this stale package from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget cache the packages in %UserProfile%/.nuget/packages folder. When you install a nuget package, it will check the cache first to see if the package is already exist. If yes, it will install the package from cache directly instead of downloading from nuget source. Since you didn't update the version of Package A, it will install the old package in the cache folder. So you need to clean to cache to make it works.

By the way, it is not recommended to push more than one packages with same version. Refer to this similar issue for details: [How does NuGet decide whether to use local package cache or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691698/how-does-nuget-decide-whether-to-use-local-package-cache-or-not).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently :

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
```

Is not actually v3 cache.  It's just named that way so you get confused.

v3 Cache is located here:

```
 C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages
```

And this is where my zombie package was coming from, and the command "Update-package -reinstall", who's documentation makes no mention of using the cache if it's available, does not fix this issue.

Comment: Could you provide the detailed steps about this dependency problem in VS2015? It could help us reproduce this issue and understanding it.

Comment: I will add a reply with the steps to reproduce.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is specific to VS2015.  It's just what I'm using at the moment.  The same thing might happen in VS2013, but I can't be bothered to check.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to reproduce this error.

1) Create a nuget package-A with a dependency that references package-B, another package that exists.

2) Install package-A in a project (package-B should come with it).

3) Delete package-B (from the nuget source) and attempt to re-install package-A. You should get an error where nuget cannot find a dependency: package-B.

4) Modify package-A to reference an older version of package-B that is still available.

5) Try to re-install package-A within the project (now that you have deployed a fixed nuget package with the same version number), you will continue to get an error until you clear the package cache.

Comment: Do you re-pack and re-install package-A after deleting package-B? I delete the package-B and re-pack package-A, but I don't get any error when re-install package in my project.

Comment: @Bitfiddler Can you increase the version of Package A and then try again? It should works correctly with increased version number.

Comment: @wendy, Yes I re-packed and attempted to re-install.  But the re-install command always took the package from the cache (until I cleared the cache by hand) so when Nuget did it's dependency resolution and tried to get meta-data from the server for packageB, it was missing and gave an error.

Comment: @Eddie - Increasing the version number would probably work, except I didn't like the idea of increasing the version number when no internal code had changed (only a broken package reference).  I thought re-install would go get a fresh copy of everything from the source, not fetch cached packages and re-add them to your project.

Comment: @Eddie - I guess in my mind, what -reinstall does is more like a 'repair' rather than a re-install.  To me, if I am thinking of re-installing an app I am thinking that I remove everything related to that app, then get a fresh copy of the installer (whether from media cd/dvd/usb or a fresh download from the vendor site) and redo the install.  What nuget re-install does is more like launching add/remove programs and running a 'repair' to potentially fix registry references and such, but you are not actually getting a fresh install from the source.

Comment: I also understand why Nuget does things this way, my particular scenario is probably exceedingly rare and not worth changing Nuget to accommodate.  It's more of a linguistic issue than anything else.